# Realm data Insertion took over 7mins for big size json

Tags: swift, insert, realm, alamofire, swifty-json

I use Alamofire to download big json data which was about around 7MB and use RealmSwift to store data at realmobject and SwiftyJSON to parse.My realm object insertion after it finished download the json seems really slow at insertion.Was something wrong with my bad code?Please guide me.

First of all I will show simplest Json :

```
{
    {
        "Start" : "40000",
        "End" : "1000000",
        "Name" : "Smith",
        "Address" : "New York"
    },{...},more than 7000 records...
}
```

Here is my AlamofireAPI Protocol

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

protocol RequestDataAPIProtocol{
    func didSuccessDownloadingData(results:JSON,statusCode : Int)
    func didFailDownloadingData(err : NSError)
}

class RequestDataAPI{

var delegate : RequestDataAPIProtocol
init(delegate: RequestDataAPIProtocol){
    self.delegate=delegate
}

func post(requestURL:String,param:[String:String]){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL, parameters: param)
        .validate(statusCode: [200,500])
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                self.delegate.didFailDownloadingData(error)
            } else if let jsonObject: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(jsonObject)
                self.delegate.didSuccessDownloadingData(json,statusCode: (response.response?.statusCode)!)
            }
        })
}

func doRequestSiteData(token : String){
    post(REQUEST_DATA,param:["data":"All","token":token])
}

}
```

Here is my Realm DB Helper

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DBHelper{

func insertUserData(list: UserList){
    do {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try realm.write({ () -> Void in
            realm.add(list,update: true)
        })
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Insert Error : \(error)")
    }
}
}
```

Here is my realm modelObject

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class UserList: Object {

     dynamic var start : String = ""
     dynamic var end : String = ""
     dynamic var name : String = ""
     dynamic var address : String = ""

}
```

And Final Code,View Controller,

```
class ViewController : UIViewController , RequestDataAPIProtocol{
       var dbHelper = DBHelper()
       var requestDataAPI : RequestDataAPI!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           requestDataAPI = RequestDataAPI(delegate : self)
       }

       override func viewDidAppear(animated : Bool){
            //assume there is one token to request data
            requestDataAPI.doRequestSiteData(token)
       }

       func didSuccessDownloadingData(results: JSON, statusCode: Int){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            print("Downloaded JSON")
            switch statusCode{
            case 200 :
               if results.count > 0{
                   if let users = results.array {
                      for user in users{
                         let userList=UserList()
                         userList.start=user["Start”].stringValue
                         userList.end=user[“End”].stringValue
                         userList.name=user[“Name”].stringValue
                         userList.address =user[“Address”].stringValue
                         self.dbHelper.insertUserData(userList)
                      }
                   }
               }
               // took about more than 7 mins
               print(“Insertion Done”)
               break

           case 500,401,400 :
               //TODO: 
           default : break
           }
        })
    }
}
```

**I know its really stupid about describing all the code steps,I write as simple as i could for my working flow for inserting json data into realm swift.**

I just want all to know about my working flow is good or bad when handling so many json data,and also insertion.

The reason why I am asking this was the data insertion took about more than 7 mins to finish.

So,I really need help,to make optimize at my code.

Any guide?

***UPDATE : I use Delegate and Protocol from RequestDataAPI which i learn that style from JamesQueue Tutorial because I am completely beginner who is still learning Swift.ViewController is updated.That is my whole process detail,no more code left.Editing my question or answer a new is appreciated for code optimizing.***

Comment: Do this 7 mins include the time it takes to download and the time it takes to parse the JSON and create the representation?

Comment: You will see my comment at view controller where it finished all progress. "print(“Insertion Done”)" took about more than 7mins to appear,and  "print("Downloaded JSON")" only took a few mins to appear. So,yes,both.

Comment: So, you don't really measure the time it takes to insert the given data into Realm. For example, on a slow connection it may take "ages" to download 7 Mbyte. You should really measure the time it takes to _insert_ the _given_ data into Realm - and not including anything else. You can figure this out using Instruments - without changing your code, or include a "stop watch" into your code. I would recommend the latter, and log the elapsed time to the console. You might also log the duration for the download and the duration to parse the JSON (including creating the representation).

Comment: Downloading didn't take too much time,yeah i tested."Downloaded Json" only took 10 seconds.Yeah,the problem exists at insertion and parsing json start from the loop.Any ideas how to make it perfect and optimize?And from my code,what do you think?was it usual way? If I am doing wrong,any guide is appreciated.

Comment: There are a couple of things that can be improved in your code, for example, you insert the items on the main thread. It's preferable to submit lengthy actions on a secondary thread. Then your `didSuccessDownloadingData` is an asynchronous function, but does not have a completion handler. Then, regarding performance, it's still not clear, where the most cycles will be spend. So, in order to (possibly) help you, please provide more details, that is, the _actual name of the function_ that costs the most. Use Instruments to figure that out. If Realm is the culprit, it should be `insertUserData`.

Comment: @6245Htarwara `insertUserData` method method opens transactions so many times in the loop. Can you try to put out to open/commit a transaction outside of the loop. In other words, open the transaction before entering the loop, and commits the transaction once after the end of the loop.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi Exactly, the list of users should be inserted within one (or a few) `try realm.write({ <insert users> })` write transaction.

Comment: Sorry that i reply late.And thanks for all of your help at yesterday.I have updated the code.As you can see I use delegate and protocol for transferring the data when the async is finish,If I need completion handler to use,code help is appreciated.And also,i thought realm would be simpler.So,I created that transactions like that.So,please edit my code or create new answer is appreciated.Thanks guys.Yeah the problem is at insertion data with loop which is doing transaction all the time that loop is going.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi,mind if u tell me how to?I am really sorry to say that,I am completely new at Realm,I just change from SQLite and try to test that as a new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`insertUserData` method method opens transactions so many times in the loop. To commit transaction is a little bit expensive operation.

Can you try to put out to open/commit a transaction outside of the loop?
In other words, open the transaction before entering the loop, and commits the transaction once after the end of the loop. Like the following:

```
if results.count > 0 {
    if let users = results.array {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try realm.write {
            for user in users{
                let userList=UserList()
                userList.start=user["Start”].stringValue
                userList.end=user[“End”].stringValue
                userList.name=user[“Name”].stringValue
                userList.address =user[“Address”].stringValue
                realm.add(userList,update: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://puu.sh/nKGvP/56b3deec2f.png. Thats how i did for now before i have seen your result.Yeah,like you said,its pretty fast when i done like that.

Comment: Looks like you are from realm.Thanks for helping me by the way.Really helpful for beginner like us.If you still can,i want you to help with another problem.Realm got observeValue at its documentation and I don't know how to use it.Here is my another case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030347/inserting-data-into-realm-db-with-progress.I hope you will join.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed slow insertion issue by using this code.

```
func addAsBatch<T: Object>(_ data: [T]) {
    if !isRealmAccessible() { return }

    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.refresh()

    realm.beginWrite()
    for object in data {
        realm.add(object)
    }
    try? realm.commitWrite()
}
```

Showing function use with your example -

```
let userList = UserList()
userList.start = user["Start”].stringValue
userList.end = user[“End”].stringValue
userList.name = user[“Name”].stringValue
userList.address  = user[“Address”].stringValue

addAsBatch(userList)
```